# Status code 412 when trying to get response from chinese website

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib

My code below returns <Response [412]> on Python, but accessing from Chrome has no problem.

```
import requests

response = requests.get("http://dzs.customs.gov.cn/dzs/2747042/3995819/ls/3997385", # /index.html
                     headers={'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
                              'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
                              'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pt-BR;q=0.8,pt;q=0.7',
                              'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
                              'Connection': 'keep-alive',                                  
                              'Host': 'dzs.customs.gov.cn',
                              'Referer': 'http://dzs.customs.gov.cn/dzs/2747042/3995819/ls/',
                              'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                              'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36'})

print(response)
```

Comment: Most likely one of the headers that's being sent by Chrome differs from the Python equivalent.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/412 for the meaning of the "412" error code.  Also look into the headers Chrome is sending: https://mkyong.com/computer-tips/how-to-view-http-headers-in-google-chrome/

Comment: @SarahMesser - All headers from my code I got from Chrome using the steps from the second link you've sent.

Comment: So the headers should be matching exactly?  Including possible typos and case?  Can you set up a dummy endpoint (with flask or some such) to record incoming requests, and confirm what's sent is the same for both programs?  Am wondering if you've recorded the headers from the remote server's response rather than what Chrome's _sending_.

Comment: Look at the `response.text` of the result. The server is sending back a JavaScript challenge which must be solved and the answer sent as a cookie, before you can proceed. You will need to solve the challenge that is sent back. Be aware: this is intentional. The server you are trying to request is purposefully giving you trouble to prevent scraping the contents.

Comment: @alxgmpr - I'm using Python 3 on Spyder and `print(response.text)` returns a scramble of letters, numbers and symbols that I cannot make sense of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using [Selenium-wire with undetected chromedriver](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/#bot-detection).

> Selenium Wire will integrate with undetected-chromedriver if it finds
> it in your environment. This library will transparently modify
> ChromeDriver to prevent it from triggering anti-bot measures on
> websites.
>
> If you wish to take advantage of this make sure you have
> undetected_chromedriver installed:
>
> ```
> pip install undetected-chromedriver
> ```
>
> Then in your code, import the seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver
> package:
>
> ```
> import seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver as uc
>
> chrome_options = uc.ChromeOptions()
>
> driver = uc.Chrome(
>     options=chrome_options,
>     seleniumwire_options={}
> )
> ```